# erase duplicate elements keeping order

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I would like to eliminate duplicate elements from a vector while keeping the vector in the current order.

Below I have a proposed implementation.  First, is this safe?

Second, is there a better way to do it, either more efficiently or better from a "using C++ algorithms and not reinventing the wheel" perspective.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<int> v= {1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 2, 9, 10, 1, 2, 2, 1};
    std::vector<int>::iterator finalEnd = v.end();
    for (auto vIter = v.begin(); vIter != v.end(); ++vIter) {
        for (auto nextvIter = vIter + 1; nextvIter != v.end(); ++nextProjIter) {
            if (*vIter == *nextvIter)
                finalEnd = std::remove(vIter, finalEnd, *nextvIter);
        }
    }
    v.erase(finalEnd, v.end());

    for(auto p : v)
        cout << p << "  ";

    //Should return:  1  7  2  3  8  4  5  6  9  10

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: No, I'm afraid the shown logic is fatally flawed and has certain edge cases where it will fail. And, yes, to answer the question that's being asked, yes, there is a much better way to do it, using a set or an unordered_set to keep track of duplicates. Should take about half as much code, and be much simpler, using only one loop. See your C++ textbook for more information on using sets and other associative containers.

Comment: Use std::set if possible. Elements are ordered and duplicates are not possible (at least for POD types from scratch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of many ways this can be accomplished it to use [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to keep track of duplicates and [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) to partition the duplicates from the lone values while preserving the order of the items:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> numSet;
    std::vector<int> v= {1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 2, 9, 10, 1, 2, 2, 1};
    auto iter = std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int n) 
           { bool ret = !numSet.count(n); numSet.insert(n); return ret; }); // returns true if the item has not been "seen"
    v.erase(iter, v.end());           
    for(auto p : v)
        std::cout << p << "  ";
}
```

Output:

```
1  7  2  3  8  4  5  6  9  10
```

The `std::stable_partition` will return `true` if the item has not been seen, thus place it to the left of the partition point.  Once done, an iterator to the partition point is returned, and we use this iterator to do one single erasure from that point to the end of the vector.  Note that the lambda function updates the `unordered_set` for each item processed.

The reason why `std::stable_partition` was used instead of `std::remove_if` is that `std::remove_if` is not guaranteed to process the items in order.  For example, it could have been possible for an implementation to process the second `1` in that data first, instead of the first `1`.  So to be safe `stable_partition` will not erase elements, but simply place the elements in the correct position, ready for the erasure at the end.

Comment: Paul, this works well and answers the question.  One more thing: in my desire to simplify the problem, I used int as the datatype in the original question. In fact, my data is of boost::filesystem::path objects. When I use the above function on a vector of path objects, I get errors in MSVC 2019, specifically 'std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function.   I realize this isn't part of the original post, but if you had any suggestion to this, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: The issue is probably that the objects for a `std::unordered_set` requires that they have a requisite hash function (you will need to provide it as the second template argument to `unordered_set`.  Since you are using boost, there is [boost::hash](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html).  Maybe create a hash on the full path name would be one way to devise such a hash for filesystem path's.

Answer (score 0):

By constructing a new vector, you can initialize this vector to be non-duplicate. You can use the find function for this. I suggest you search for std :: find

```
std::vector<int> v= {1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 2, 9, 10, 1, 2, 2, 1};
std::vector<int> nonDuplicateVect;

for (int element : v)
    if(std::find(nonDuplicateVect.begin(), nonDuplicateVect.end(), element) == nonDuplicateVect.end())
        nonDuplicateVect.push_back(element);

for (int element : nonDuplicateVect)
    std::cout << element << " ";

std::cout << "\n";
```